# dryRun Implementation in Karate

Tags: karate

Just wondering if we have the dryRun functionality of cucumber in Karate ? I have gone through the information in this link - https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/434 but it doesn't really tell me if  a solution has been implemented or not. If not explicit to "dryRun" do we have a functionality within Karate that does the same operation as Cucumber ?

I have a framework and would like to know the overall count / scenarios that has been scripted and running it without the dryRun tag is a bit of an overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@qatestprofile

I have created Karate demo project with [Dry Run example](https://github.com/workwithprashant/karate-demo-examples/tree/1.0/dry_run_example) which generates HTML scenario table using Karate's Dry Run option and you can use the code as per your need.

Note: This demo example can be improved so feel free to suggest.

Comment: I think `--dryrun` or `-D` will work even within `karate.options`, can you try that once

Comment: Thanks @Prashant, Unfortunately I am on a very old version of Karate ( 0.9.5 ) and will not be able to update my version to the latest where I see most of your changes sit. I will mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @PeterThomas —dryrun works too within karate.options, I just wanted to show how you can use thymeleaf template to generate HTML table as per need.